# Get videos from youtube api v3 with 2 part username

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**EDIT**
I seem to be able to get videos from a username if the username is only  word. But not from channels with double word usernames(eg. names with a space in between).

Im trying to get videos through the v3 api of youtube. Ive done it before but this time i cannot get it to work.

```
        $.get(
           "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
               part: 'contentDetails',
               forUsername: 'Gunnar+Base',
               id: 'UCI8vMgRRdio_jtoNbZ6dIlw',
               key: 'xxx',
           },
           function (data) {
               $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                   pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                   console.log(pid);

                  //DO another call for the videos and loop them out.
               });
           }
        );
```

This code works well for another project. Ive enabled the api and got a key. The only problem is youtube cannot find any channels related to the account. The account has several uploaded videos though. Im testing calls through the API explorer but it seems it cannot find the user. I can find other channels though this though. The only thing that differs is that I have 2 words in as channel name. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Answer (score 0):

This might be the stupidest thing ever. If you have a double word username you have to find your channelid instead and use that instead of fromUsername.

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
               part: 'contentDetails',
               id: 'Channelid',
               key: 'xx',
           },
```

instead of

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
                   part: 'contentDetails',
                   fromUsername: 'Username Secondword',
                   key: 'xx',
               },
```